# jquery: why can't I fade image on Chrome when the image is loaded?

Tags: jquery, image, google-chrome, fadeout

I don't understand this - why can't I fade image on Chrome when the image is loaded?

the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $('.image').fadeOut('slow',function(){

        });

    });
```

the html,

```
<body>
<img src="pic-1.jpg" class="image"/>
</body>
```

But it works fine on all other browers, including IE!

Any idea what I have done wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is the entire code I am testing it on Chrome and other browsers,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').fadeOut('slow');
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
        <img src="pic-1.jpg"/>

</body>
</html>
```

I think I read it somewhere before that it is to do with how the image is loaded on Chrome. But I can't remember how it works now!

Any idea?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Got it fix like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).bind('load', function() {
            $('img').fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
```

Comment: You're missing some details, the above works fine in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/yDCK5/1/

Comment: i'm on jquery 1.61 - does it cause a problem on Chrome??

Comment: I also ran it with the latest version of jquery ( v1.6.2pre ) and it worked without issue, on chrome

Comment: I don't understand why it does not work on mine! arggg...

Comment: does the JS fiddle version run for you? If it does then you need to post more information as its obviously something else causing the problem

Comment: just posted the entire code that I am testing it on Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because `$(document).ready()` fires when the html is done loading, not after images are done loading.  Weird fix, but try wrapping a div around the image and fading that out on ready instead.  Alternately, call `$('img').fadeOut('slow');` on `.load()` instead of `.ready()`.